# CEFSharp - Automated login

Tags: javascript, html, cefsharp

I'm trying to control navigation around a website opened & displayed via CEFSharp from VB.Net.
I'm trying to login into the site.
The login page includes the following code.

```
<form method="post" ACTION="signin.asp" name="MyLogin">
  <p>Email address</p><input type="text" name="usr">
  <br /><br />
  <p>Password</p><input type="password" name="pwd"">
  <br /><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="dologin" value="yes">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I'm successfully using the following to load the "usr" textbox (& similar for "pwd"). NB byName as no "id" present.

```
Dim sScript as string = "document.getElementsByName('usr')[0].value='" & zUsername & "';"
Dim oResult = oBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(sScript)
```

How do I perform a click (or post) to then login? "dologin" is hidden. "submit" has no id or name to then use something like

```
Dim sScript as string = "document.all('submit').click();"
Dim oResult = oBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(sScript)
```

Comment: I'd suggest opening your website in Chrome, using DevTools to execute JavaScript for testing purposes,  much easier to debug. Then once you have the JavaScript working try executing it using CefSharp. You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector it's not clear what the purpose of dologin is.

Comment: amaitland - Thanks. need to spend some proper times looking the DevTools. When I previously looked I gave up. I have AdBlocker installed its code seemed to "dwarf" the interesting code.

Have sorted the issue with ...
Dim sScript as string = "document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').click();"